# Output values to buffers of different sizes

Tags: c++, halide

I need to output 2 values to buffers of different sizes. One is the same size as the input, and the other one is half the width and half the height. I thought of using tuples, but I'm getting outside the bounds since it's iterating over the input size. Here's a quick example:

```
uint8_t _in[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
uint8_t _out1[4];
uint8_t _out2[1];

Buffer<uint8_t> in(_in, 2, 2);
Buffer<uint8_t> out1(_out1, 2, 2);
Buffer<uint8_t> out2(_out2, 1, 1);

Var x, y;
Func f;

f(x, y) = {
    in(x,y),
    in(x / 2, y / 2)
};

f.realize({ out1, out2 });
```

Are tuples not the right solution for this?

Comment: It's the same Tuple at each x,y, so the Buffers have to be the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a `Halide::Pipeline` using the two output `Funcs` and call `realize` on the `Pipeline` object.

Something like so:

```
uint8_t _in[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
uint8_t _out1[4];
uint8_t _out2[1];

Buffer<uint8_t> in(_in, 2, 2);
Buffer<uint8_t> out1(_out1, 2, 2);
Buffer<uint8_t> out2(_out2, 1, 1);

Var x, y;
Func f1, f2;

f1(x, y) = in(x,y);
f2(x, y) = in(x / 2, y / 2);

Pipeline pipeline({f1, f2});

pipeline.realize({ out1, out2 });
```

Comment: Will the Pipeline be able to execute the two `Func`s in parallel in this case?

Comment: Depends on the scheduling. Halide's only way to do thread parallelism at present is to parallelize a dimension of a Func. For this case, it can be done by having a Func with a single index that takes on values 0 and 1 and then selects on the index to compute something that depends on out1 or out2, but I'm reluctant to write that out here as a) a comment reply isn't the right place to do it and b) it doesn't seem indicative of the real problems one wants to solve. Generally multiple outputs are used to capture more than one thing computed by a well scheduled pipeline.